# Stop scrollbar from pushing content left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a website and I have multiple pages that use the same template, some pages are longer than the browser window's height, other's aren't. The ones that are longer get pushed to he left by about 10px, this might no sound like much but it's noticeable when switching pages as everything jumps sideways.

Is there some CSS thing I can do to make the scroll bar on each page appear over the content rather than pushing it, I have a margin in the template so if the browser window is too small it will just cover the margin when the user scrolls to the far right.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean that you center your body like this: `body{ width: 800px; margin: 0px auto; }`? What do you mean with 'I have a margin in the template'? Please add your code so we see what's actually happening.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only way to do this is to have the scrollbar always visible.

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: +1 - This really is the cleanest approach - and the only cross-browser one I know of

Comment: Unfortunately it is deprecated and no longer supported in Firefox

Answer (score 9):

Give overflow value as overlay. This will avoid the recalculation of layout when scrollbar appears

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543664/overflow-overlay-doesnt-work-in-firefox . Also the MDN web doc's doesn't recommend using it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score -1):

Overflow: overlay worked for me. Would've commented on jintoppy's post but I'm a nooob