# Overflow: overlay doesn't work in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, properties, overflow

On my website I need to use the css property `overflow: overlay` for a `<div>`.

However, it is not rendering in the browser and an inspection of the css in firebug shows that it isn't even there, but it is as it works in Chrome. I havn't tested out safari.

What must I change to get the `overflow: overlay` css property working?

Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Possible values for overflow are:

```
visible
hidden
auto
scroll
```

See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html) or [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) for a discussion of these.

Using any other value in different browsers will yield unpredictable results as they handle the incorrect value differently.

**Edit**: Following the comment, I've managed to find mention of overflow:overlay [here](http://help.dottoro.com/lcawqfhe.php).

overlay is described as:

> Content is clipped and scroll bars are added when necessary.

Importantly its also said only to work in Safari or Chrome (ie WebKit).

[This item](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32388) on WebKit bugzilla suggest it is not long for this world in any case:

> WebKit currently has a proprietary CSS overflow value called "overlay" which is undocumented and as far as I can tell from reading the code works exactly like "auto".
>
> We should either remove it or rename it to "-webkit-overlay".

**Update March 2016**

Looks like `overflow: overlay` hasn't gone away. There are signs of it working it's way into the standards.

The difference between `overlay` and `auto` would only be that the scrollbars would appear over the top of the page content, and not cause it to take layout space.

See [here for the discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/92).

Comment: Overlay works the same as Auto. (scroll bars are added when necessary)

Comment: There is a difference, though: With `auto`, the scrollbar is added below the element on x-overflow. With `overlay`, it is added within the element! This means that no additional screen estate is taken, but the text within the element itself is obstructed by the scrollbar. It is a subtle, but useful difference. Tested on Chromium.

Comment: "overflow: overlay" is not the same as "overflow : auto". In case you style the scrollbar by giving it some width, then both these properties have different effects. In case of overlay, the scrollbar does not push the content in anyway as it floats above the content and is not in the normal document flow. But in case of "overflow: auto", the scrollbar occupies some width (as specified by you), and pushes the content just as any inflow element would.

Comment: MDN web docs recommends not to use ```overflow: overlay``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow .Also check out this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1521631

Comment: overflow: overlay has gone, chrome 114+

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `overlay` in general, but then for Firefox, call out `scroll` specifically. Apparently Firefox implements `scroll` like Chrome etc. implements `overlay` E.g.:

```css
.container{
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
    .container{
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Allegedly, another solution is to use the `scrollbar-gutter` property. I haven't personally had luck with this yet myself -- I think major browsers might still be catching up.

Comment: Since Safari also does not support the overlay property, you could also include a rule to account for safari browser:
@supports  (background: -webkit-named-image(i)) or (-moz-appearance:none)
Here you can test, if it's still working at the time of reading this: https://jsbin.com/yoqecol/edit?css,output

Comment: scrollbar-gutter is nothing like overflow: overlay, scrollbar-gutter only use is to reserve space, where overflow: overlay removes that space for a more transient scrollbar UX, like on mobile devices.