# How to set tbody height with overflow scroll

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem while setting tbody height width overflow scroll.

```
<style> 
     tbody{
       height:50px;display:block;overflow:scroll
     }
   </style>

       <h3>Table B</h3>
    <table style="border: 1px solid red;width:300px;display:block">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>phone</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style='height:50px;display:block;overflow:scroll'>
            <tr>
                <td>AAAA</td>
                <td>323232</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BBBBB</td>
                <td>323232</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CCCCC</td>
                <td>3435656</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[Visit my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/amit4mins/f2XYF)

I want table B like Table A with overflow scroll.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks,
M.

Comment: Can't understand. You want Table B like table A with overflow scroll but table A hasn't overflow, table B has.

Comment: Alek : When i set height of tbody with overflow scroll and display block then design goes messive.

Comment: Alignment should be like table A. got it?

Answer (score 369, accepted):

If you want `tbody` to show a scrollbar, set its `display: block;`.

Set `display: table;` for the `tr` so that it keeps the behavior of a table.

To evenly spread the cells, use `table-layout: fixed;`.

(edit 08-2023)**Disclaimer** : read till the bottom of the answer. Now days, you can probably switch to a grid layout to avoid side-effects.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f2XYF/8/)**  [image: tbody scroll]

---

CSS:

```
table, tr td {
    border: 1px solid red
}
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
table {
    width: 400px;
}
```

---

If `tbody` doesn't show a scroll, because content is less than `height` or `max-height`, set the scroll any time with: `overflow-y: scroll;`. **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/f2XYF/16/)**

---

**`<editS/updateS>`** 2019 - 04/2021

---

- **Important note:** this approach to making a table scrollable has drawbacks in some cases. (See comments below.) *some of the duplicate answers in this thread deserves the same warning by the way*

> WARNING: this solution disconnects the thead and tbody cell grids; which means that in most practical cases, you will not have the cell alignment you expect from tables. Notice this solution uses a hack to keep them sort-of aligned: thead { width: calc( 100% - 1em ) }

- Anyhow, to set a scrollbar, a display reset is needed to get rid of the table-layout (which will never show scrollbar).
- Turning the `<table>` into a grid via `display:grid`/`contents` will also leave a gap in between header and scrollable part, to mind about. (idem if built from divs)
- `overflow:overlay;` has not yet shown up in Firefox *( keep watching it)*
- `position:sticky` will require a parent container which can be the scrolling one. make sure your `thead` can be sticky if you have a few rows and `rowspan/colspan` headers in it (it does not with chrome).

**So far, there is no perfect solution yet via CSS only**. there is a few average ways to choose along so it fits your own table (table-layout:fixed; is .. fixing table and column's width, but javascript could probably be used to reset those values =>  exit pure CSS)

Comment: GCyrillus : you are closest. But there is one issue. table width went too high. Can we fix table width?

Comment: @Maverick do you have an exemple  with table width too high ? do you mean something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/f2XYF/16/

Comment: Sorry, I do not have example. If we talk about code provided by you its not taking width defined in above code means: table {
    width:400px;
}

Comment: @Maverick reset anywidth you want to table. make sure you apply CSS over a table that has no style attributes, else , the css sheet will be override by inline style.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GCyrillus it works great ! May I suggest one tip ? Replace `overflow:auto` by `overflow-y: scroll` to avoid headers to stay 1em left even when body does not need scrollbar.

Comment: Finally! I'm now able to have a fixed height, scrolling table body, fixed headers, adjustable column widths .... all without javascript! Thank you!!

Comment: With a small change in CSS:
thead tr, tbody tr{
}
It worked great, Thank you G-Cyr.

Comment: When `display: table` is a requirement for your design, this is by far the only working solution I could find

Comment: WARNING: this solution disconnects the thead and tbody cell grids; which means that in most practical cases, you will not have the cell alignment you expect from tables. Notice this solution uses a hack to keep them sort-of aligned: thead { width: calc( 100% - 1em ) }

Comment: @G-Cyr I call it a hack because it only estimates the width of the scrollbar, and makes one case look like the 2 grids are (sort-of) connected, but in reality they are not and will misalign in most expanded use uses. I would be wary to deploy this solution to a production UI, for ex. -- hence the warning.

Comment: using javascript to comput width of columns on tbody according to the corresponding thead is something that helped me. adding some methods to handle scrollbar width and colspan soved my issue.

Comment: Use `overflow-y: overlay;` so you can remove the `padding-right: 1em;`. Really makes everything look better.

Comment: @Allart , it would probably be a good advice for nowdays, **can you  set a codepen to show us that it works fine or even add your own answer** ;) (Firefox) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543664/overflow-overlay-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Comment: I have found that the CSS rule for thead `width: calc( 100% - 0.85em )` works better in Mozilla FireFox than `width: calc( 100% - 1em )`.

Answer (score 135):

Another approach is to wrap your table in a scrollable element and set the header cells to stick to the top.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to change the display on tbody and you can leave it to the browser to calculate column width while keeping the header cell widths in line with the data cell column widths.

```css
/* Set a fixed scrollable wrapper */
.tableWrap {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
/* Set header to stick to the top of the container. */
thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

/* If we use border,
we must use table-collapse to avoid
a slight movement of the header row */
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Because we must set sticky on th,
 we have to apply background styles here
 rather than on thead */
th {
  padding: 16px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 1px dotted rgba(200, 209, 224, 0.6);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  background: #ffc491;
  text-align: left;
  /* With border-collapse, we must use box-shadow or psuedo elements
  for the header borders */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 2px #e8e8e8;
}

/* Basic Demo styling */
table {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
table td {
  padding: 16px;
}
tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
}
thead {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
tbody tr:hover {
  background: #e6f7ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableWrap">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Month</span></th>
        <th>
          <span>Event</span>
        </th>
        <th><span>Action</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February. An extra long string.</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>March</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>April</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>May</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>June</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>August</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>September</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>November</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>December</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td><span>Invite | Delete</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea! It does not mess the table layout like the other options do.

Comment: Reminder to anyone else that you need to make sure no ancestor elements are using overflow. Could cause position: sticky to not work

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/position-sticky-not-working-css-and-html/47878455

Comment: Another cool aspect of this solution is that it works with `height: 100%`

Comment: IE doesn't support position: sticky

Comment: FWIW you can also add a `tfoot` with a sticky bottom position of 0 and it works like a charm. Great answer!

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer ? All the other ones are doing cowboy hacks with scrollbar widths, alignment, breaking table properties...

Comment: Eventually I went for this option. Easy to implement and more maintainable. Thanks!

Answer (score 93):

It is simple way to use scroll bar to table body

```css
/* It is simple way to use scroll bar to table body*/

table tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table thead, table tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Invoice Number</th>
    <th>Purchaser</th>
    <th>Invoice Amount</th>
    <th>Invoice Date</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>INV-1233</td>
      <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
      <td>$300</td>
      <td>01/12/2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Far from perfect, forces all columns to be the same width

Comment: Is there a way to do this without setting the height of the body?

Comment: I will work on it... but If we did not use height, so all the records will display at a time there will be no vertical scroll bar.  thanks @shinzou

Comment: @stackers You can set column widths by adding `width: 100px` to `td, th` inside `tbody, thead`

Comment: I am facing a problem on this method. When i put display:block for the table its getting messed. But i couldn't get the scroll view without putting display:block. Any solution for this ??

Answer (score 12):

By default `overflow` does not apply to table group elements unless you give a `display:block` to `<tbody>`  also you have to give a `position:relative` and `display: block` to `<thead>`.  Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vujoyubu/1/edit)**.

```
.fixed {
  width:350px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed th {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fixed th,
.fixed td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 200px;
}


.fixed thead {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}
.fixed thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without setting the height of the body?

Comment: doesn't fully work. if the column name is wider than the column content, it misaligns it.

Answer (score 9):

**Simplest of all solutions:**

Add the below code in CSS:

```
.tableClassName tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.tableClassName thead, .tableClassName tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tableClassName thead {
  width: calc( 100% - 1.1em );
}
```

> **1.1 em** is the average width of the scroll bar, please modify this if needed.

Comment: The syntax on the 2nd rule is incorrect, as it ends up selecting ALL `tbody tr` elements on the page.
Change to:
`.tableClassName thead, .tableClassName tbody tr {...}`

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56998444/123545), here's a minimal solution if you're already using Bootstrap:

```css
div.scrollable-table-wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;

  thead tr th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-table-wrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Tested on Bootstrap v3

Comment: Useless in IE.  In other browsers, the row contents bleed through the header text while scrolling, so you'll also need to set a background-color on the <th> to cover them up. If none of  your users are on IE, this is a workable solution.

Comment: I'm using this solution with `div.scrollable-table-wrapper > table > thead tr th {...}`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled across it when attempting to make a sticky header & footer.  I found this [post with a simple solution that seems to work well for what I need](https://css-tricks.com/making-tables-with-sticky-header-and-footers-got-a-bit-easier/).

```
table thead,
table tfoot {
  position: sticky;
}
table thead {
  inset-block-start: 0; /* "top" */
}
table tfoot {
  inset-block-end: 0; /* "bottom" */
}
```

Comment: nice, really nice!

Comment: While this works, there is no scrollbar/scroller or any indication that it is scrolllable.

Answer (score 3):

Change your second table code like below.

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red;width:300px;display:block;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td width=150>Name</td>
        <td width=150>phone</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style='height:50px;overflow:auto;display:block;width:317px;'>
    <tr>
        <td width=150>AAAA</td>
        <td width=150>323232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BBBBB</td>
        <td>323232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CCCCC</td>
        <td>3435656</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2v64W/)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without setting the height of the body?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to have responsive table height instead of fixed height in pixels as the other answers are showing. To do that I used percentage of visible height property and overflow on div containing the table:

```
&__table-container {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

This way the table will expand along with the window being resized.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same solution for my project. This is how I did it.
The data is taken from one of the answers above for demonstration purpose.

```css
.tableContainer {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}


/* for styling only */

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableContainer">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Invoice Number</th>
      <th>Purchaser</th>
      <th>Invoice Amount</th>
      <th>Invoice Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>INV-1233</td>
        <td>Dinesh Vaitage</td>
        <td>$300</td>
        <td>01/12/2017</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the scrollbar from the header column?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<table id="uniquetable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> {{ field[0].key }} </th>
        <th> {{ field[1].key }} </th>
        <th> {{ field[2].key }} </th>
        <th> {{ field[3].key }} </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="obj in objects" v-bind:key="obj.id">
        <td> {{ obj.id }} </td>
        <td> {{ obj.name }} </td>
        <td> {{ obj.age }} </td>
        <td> {{ obj.gender }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#uniquetable thead{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
#uniquetable tbody{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y:overlay;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#uniquetable tbody tr,#uniquetable thead tr{
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
}
#uniquetable tbody tr td, #uniquetable thead tr th{
   display:table-cell;
   width:20% !important;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

this will work as well:

```
#uniquetable tbody {
    width:inherit !important;
    display:block;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y:overlay;
  }
  #uniquetable thead {
    width:inherit !important;
    display:block;
  }
  #uniquetable tbody tr, #uniquetable thead tr {
    display:inline-flex;
    width:100%;
  }
  #uniquetable tbody tr td,  #uniquetable thead tr th {
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    border-top:none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height:400px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do, is to keep the header fixed and to scroll the body content.
You can scroll the content into 2 directions:

- horizontally: you won't be able to scroll the content horizontally unless you use a slider (a jQuery slider for example). I would recommend to avoid using a table in this case.
- vertically: you won't be able to achieve that with a `tbody` tag, because assigning `display:block` or `display:inline-block` will break the layout of the table.

Here's a solution using `divs`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2XYF/13/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap_header">
    <div class="column">
        Name
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        Phone
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap_body">
    <div class="sliding_wrapper">
        <div class="serie">
            <div class="cell">
                AAAAAA
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                323232
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="serie">
            <div class="cell">
                BBBBBB
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                323232
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="serie">
            <div class="cell">
                CCCCCC
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                3435656
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap_header{width:204px;}
.sliding_wrapper,
.wrap_body {width:221px;}
.sliding_wrapper {overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:none;}
.sliding_wrapper,
.wrap_body {height:45px;}
.wrap_header,
.wrap_body {overflow:hidden;}
.column {width:100px; float:left; border:1px solid red;}
.cell {width:100px; float:left; border:1px solid red;}

/**
 * @info Clearfix: clear all the floated elements
 */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    content:" ";
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
.clearfix {display:inline-table;}

/**
 * @hack Display the Clearfix as a block element
 * @hackfor Every browser except IE for Macintosh
 */
    /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
    * html .clearfix {height:1%;}
    .clearfix {display:block;}
    /* End hide from IE-mac */
```

Explanation:

You have a `sliding wrapper` which will contain all the data.

Note the following:

```
.wrap_header{width:204px;}
.sliding_wrapper,
.wrap_body {width:221px;}
```

There's a difference of 17px because we need to take into consideration the width of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit seems to use internally `display: table-row-group` for the `tbody` tag.
There is currently a bug with setting height to it: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/476

Let's hope it will be solved soon.

Answer (score 0):

Making scrolling tables is always a challenge. This is a solution where the table is scrolled both horizontally and vertically with fixed height on tbody making theader and tbody "stick" (without display: sticky). I've added a "big" table just to show.
I got inspiration from G-Cyrillus to make the tbody display:block;
But when it comes to width of a cell (both in header and body), it's depending on the inside content. Therefore I added content with specific width inside each cell, both in thead and minimum first row in tbody (the other rows adapt accordingly)

```css
.go-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.go-wrapper table {
    width: auto;
}
.go-wrapper table tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.go-wrapper table thead {
    display: table;
}
.go-wrapper table tfoot {
    display: table;
}
.go-wrapper table thead tr, 
.go-wrapper table tbody tr,
.go-wrapper table tfoot tr {
    display: table-row;
}

.go-wrapper table th,
.go-wrapper table td { 
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.go-wrapper .aw-50  { min-height: 1px; width: 50px; }
.go-wrapper .aw-100 { min-height: 1px; width: 100px; }
.go-wrapper .aw-200 { min-height: 1px; width: 200px; }
.go-wrapper .aw-400 { min-height: 1px; width: 400px; }

/***** Colors *****/
.go-wrapper table {
    border: 2px solid red
}
.go-wrapper table thead, 
.go-wrapper table tbody, 
.go-wrapper table tfoot {
    outline: 1px solid green
}
.go-wrapper td {
    outline: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="go-wrapper">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" ><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-200">Name</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" >Week</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-100">Date</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-100">Time</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-200">Project</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-400">Text</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-200">Activity</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" >Hours</th>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" >Pause</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-100">Status</div></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="aw-50"><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-200">AAAAA</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-50" >15</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-100">07.04.2020</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-100">10:00</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-200">Project 1</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-400">Blah blah blah</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-200">Activity</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-50" >2t</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-50" >30min</div></td>
                                <td><div class="aw-100">Waiting</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>BBBBB</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>CCCCC</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity Activity Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>DDDDD</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>EEEEE</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>FFFFF</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity Activity Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>GGGGG</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>HHHHH</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>IIIII</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>JJJJJ</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>KKKKK</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>LLLLL</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>MMMMM</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>NNNNN</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>OOOOO</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>PPPPP</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>QQQQQ</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>RRRRR</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>SSSSS</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>TTTTT</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>UUUUU</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>VVVVV</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>XXXXX</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>YYYYY</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>ZZZZZ</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>ÆÆÆÆÆ</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>ØØØØØ</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></td>
                                <td>ÅÅÅÅÅ</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>07.04.2020</td>
                                <td>10:00</td>
                                <td>Project 1</td>
                                <td>Blah blah blah</td>
                                <td>Activity</td>
                                <td>2t</td>
                                <td>30min</td>
                                <td>Waiting</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" ><div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="styled"></span></div></div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-200">Name</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" >Week</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-100">Date</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-100">Time</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-200">Project</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-400">Text</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-200">Activity</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" >Hours</th>
                                <th><div class="aw-50" >Pause</div></th>
                                <th><div class="aw-100">Status</div></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a cool solution using grid!
This is what I used and it worked out perfectly:

```
tbody tr, thead tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; // or whatever division you wanna do
}

tbody {
  height: 300px; // or whatever height
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/table-with-inner-body-scroll-hggq7x

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good example for table scrolling across x and y way.
Horizontal and vertical scrolling is the best thing for responsive table.

```css
table, th, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  
}
tbody {
  max-height: 200px;
max-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>

    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
  </th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The row-column widths no longer match the header-column width.