# Table with display: block properties, I would like to create the row widths to 100% but doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table in CSS that's a fixed height with y-scrolling properties.  The only problem is when i set:

```
display: block;
```

then:

```
width: 100%;
```

doesn't work anymore.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead style="display: block;">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">  <!-- THIS DOESN'T WORK -->
                PLAYS
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="display: block; overflow-y: auto;" height="465px;">
        <tr ng-repeat="play in playsArray" ng-click="onSelectPlayTableClick(play)" ng-class="{'tr-rcsorange-selected': play.Selected == true}" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <td>{{play.PlayDescription}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There's no point in making a table into a block, it will loose all of it's behavior that makes it a table in the first place, you might as well save yourself from typing 2 extra letters and use a div.

Comment: i dont know how else to make a table with a fixed height and scrolling y-properties with multiple columns..

Comment: You place a div within a cell and increase the div's width and height as much as you want. It's easier when `table-layout: fixed` Read the comments in the source of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To overflow a table, you need first to kill the table-layout prperties:

```
table, thead,tbody,tr {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

then restore it deeper in HTML:

```
tr {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

from here, scroll can be used :

```
tbody {
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Full snippet/code below

```css
table,
thead,
tbody,
tr {
  display: block;
}
thead {
  margin-right:1em;
  }
tr {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
tbody {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto ; /* eventually : scroll;*/
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

some more explanation of the basic code in a similar question [How to set tbody height with overflow scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771#23989771)

Comment: this did answer the question very well which was great, but if the thead/th is the same size as the tbody/tr, the sizes are misaligned for some reason.. i'm sure because of the scroll bar

Comment: @user1189352 see the question linked or add a magin, table or not scrollbar come with a size:) (snippet edited)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
table {table-layout: fixed; }
```

Details are in the source in the comments

#### SNIPPET

```css
html,

body {

  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  overflow: hidden;

  position: relative;

}

table {

  /* A fixed table allows you to control it's width by widdening it's cells */

  table-layout: fixed;

  border: 5px dotted black;

  border-collapse: collapse;

  border-spacing: 0;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

thead,

tbody {

  border: 3px dashed blue;

}

th,

td {

  outline: 4px solid red;

}

/* In order to expand a cell, place a div inside the cell */

.spacer1 {

  min-width: 100vw;

}

.spacer2 {

  min-height: 465px;

  height: 1000px;

}

/* Scrolling and overflow can be acheived by wrapping table 
in a block element with overflow: auto/scroll and body
overflow: hidden;
*/

.box {

  overflow-y: auto;

  height: 100vh;

}
```

```html
<section class="box">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="spacer1">&nbsp;</div>
          PLAYS
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody height="465">
      <tr ng-repeat="play in playsArray" ng-click="onSelectPlayTableClick(play)" ng-class="{'tr-rcsorange-selected': play.Selected == true}" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <td>
          <div class="spacer2">{{play.PlayDescription}}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just create a div inside the TH and TD.

```html
<style>
    #cellhead {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #cellbody {
    height: 456px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <!-- display: block is a default display parameter, not required. -->
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div id="cellhead">
          PLAYS
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- display: block is a default display parameter, not required. -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="cellbody" ng-repeat="play in playsArray" ng-click="onSelectPlayTableClick(play)" ng-class="{'tr-rcsorange-selected': play.Selected == true}">
          {{play.PlayDescription}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```