# Materialize scroll tbody

Tags: css, materialize

I am facing problem while setting `tbody` height width `overflow-y: scroll`.

I tried this CSS

```
.table-status-sheet tbody{
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This is my table code

```
 <div class="responsive-table table-status-sheet">
    <table class="bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="center">No.</th>
          <th class="center">Category</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Category1</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Category2</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Category3</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Category4</td>                 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

This code is working in bootstrap but not worked in 'Materialized' theme. 
Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Could you please give more code or any link to preview this code?

Comment: You are not the only one with this problem... I'm also facing difficulties changing the height of tbody... it doesent matther what css I apply it wont change its height

Comment: @Muhammad how??

Comment: @weinde here is how I did it using css, http://stackoverflow.com/a/41066778/1966247

Answer (score 9):

Here is how you can do it.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tfb517gg/)**

```css
tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
thead {
  width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="responsive-table table-status-sheet">
    <table class="bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="center">No.</th>
          <th class="center">Category</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Category1</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Category2</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Category3</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Category4</td>                 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried this code in my project. but it is overlapping each other. because I'm using more then 12 column. What i want to do to overcome overlapping text issue?

Comment: It breaks table on mobile.

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad how it breaks table? you mean overlapping the columns?

Answer (score 0):

solution found in another Q:     [How to set tbody height with overflow scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll)

you have to set tbody to -> display:block;

```
table ,tr td{}
    tbody {
        display:block;
        height:50px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    thead, tbody tr {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    thead {
        width: calc( 100% - 1em );
    }
    table {
        width:400px;
    }
```