# Materialize css scroll table header freezing not working

Tags: html, css, html-table, materialize

I am trying to freeze table header and need to make scroll only table body. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41066778/7776881) link. But it is fine for minimal number of columns. If increases, then thus the table data text is overlapping each other. this is major bug in my project. I tried lots. But its become useless. if you have any solution please comment it below or help with your answer.

Screen Shot (For Example):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must set up a horizontal scroll for the whole table as it became larger than screen width and set each cell with a wrap property to avoid its content pass uppon the next. Try this:

```
.outer-div {
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px; //Or any default value for you.
    overflow: auto;
}

.inner-div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
}

.cell-content {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Remember to change the classes' names with yours. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But little doubt what is outer div and inner div? I'm just using table