# How to let the <table> stay on fixed height? Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with dynamic content, it can be 1 or more rows, most likely up to 200. The user should be able to click on a single row and additional content should be displayed underneath in another table list.

Now, when i search for an item, the table shrinks according to the found records, lets say i have 5 records and look for 1 record, the entire table element underneath jumps up. This is not a good ux.

I know there is a way to keep the height of the table or table body?

here is my code so far. You can search by "meyer"

```js
function reservationListFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("reservationListInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("reservationTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"),
      match = false;
      for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
        if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          match = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!match) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#reservationTable tr').each(function () {
       var td_value = $('td',this).eq(4).text();
       console.log(td_value);
       switch (td_value) {
           case 'Expected':
                $(this).addClass('table-success');
               break;
           case 'Inhouse':
                $(this).addClass('table-info');
               break;
           case 'Cancelled':
                $(this).addClass('table-danger');
               break;
           case 'Partial':
                $(this).addClass('table-warning');
               break;
           case 'Finished':
                $(this).addClass('table-active');
               break;

           default:
               // statements_def
               break;
       }
    });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggle");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



        <div class="container" style="" id="reservationListTable">
            <div class="row">
                    
                </div>
            <input style="margin-top:0.5em" class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationListInput" onkeyup="reservationListFunction()" placeholder="Search for reservation..">

           
            <div classs="container">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-fixed table-fixedResList" id="reservationTable">
                <thead class="">
                    <tr class="header">
                        <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Cabin</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Guests</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Table</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs-down" style="width:10%;">Status</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs-down" style="width:5%;">SR</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs-down" style="width:5%;">DOB</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="">
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Julia Sanders</td>
                        <td class="">10293</td>
                        <td class="">4</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Cancelled</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Mirko Meyer</td>
                        <td class="">13293</td>
                        <td class="">2</td>
                        <td class="">132</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Partial</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-fixed" id="reservationDetailTable">
          <tr class="header">
            <th style="width:20%;">Primary Guest</th>
            <th style="width:80%;">Info</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="8">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; border-style: solid; border-color: #ffffff;">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-circle" src="./assets/img/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Mark Meyer</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Cabin 23412</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">EDIT</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            <td>Reservation ID</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Guests Associated</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reservation Date</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Special Request</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: the snippet contains some error! edit it please!

Comment: Why don't you just give the table a fixed height with css? like #reservationTable { height: 200px; }

Comment: While giving this a height is a good thing, but I would also need to let the header stay. Otherwise it would scroll away.

Comment: @GCyrillus, what you wrote, i dont think this is what I need, but thanks.

Comment: @Stefan this actually did the trick, but do you also know how i can let my header row stay while scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, you want to give the tbody a fixed hight, so the header is always visible. How this can be done is already discribed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23989771/639035

You need the css:

```
#reservationTable thead, #reservationTable tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#reservationTable tbody {
    height: 100px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```js
function reservationListFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("reservationListInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("reservationTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"),
      match = false;
      for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
        if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          match = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!match) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#reservationTable tr').each(function () {
       var td_value = $('td',this).eq(4).text();
       console.log(td_value);
       switch (td_value) {
           case 'Expected':
                $(this).addClass('table-success');
               break;
           case 'Inhouse':
                $(this).addClass('table-info');
               break;
           case 'Cancelled':
                $(this).addClass('table-danger');
               break;
           case 'Partial':
                $(this).addClass('table-warning');
               break;
           case 'Finished':
                $(this).addClass('table-active');
               break;

           default:
               // statements_def
               break;
       }
    });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggle");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
#reservationTable thead, #reservationTable tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#reservationTable tbody {
    height: 100px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>


**Full Code:**
(Tested in Chrome)

        <div class="container" style="" id="reservationListTable">
            <div class="row">
                    
                </div>
            <input style="margin-top:0.5em" class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationListInput" onkeyup="reservationListFunction()" placeholder="Search for reservation..">

           
            <div classs="container">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-fixed table-fixedResList" id="reservationTable">
                <thead class="">
                    <tr class="header">
                        <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Cabin</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Guests</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Table</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs-down" style="width:10%;">Status</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs-down" style="width:5%;">SR</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs-down" style="width:5%;">DOB</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="">
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Julia Sanders</td>
                        <td class="">10293</td>
                        <td class="">4</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Cancelled</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Mirko Meyer</td>
                        <td class="">13293</td>
                        <td class="">2</td>
                        <td class="">132</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Partial</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td class="">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                        <td class="">49222</td>
                        <td class="">14</td>
                        <td class="">201</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">Expected</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">SR(2)</td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs-down">BD</td>
                        <td class="">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Checkin</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-fixed" id="reservationDetailTable">
          <tr class="header">
            <th style="width:20%;">Primary Guest</th>
            <th style="width:80%;">Info</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="8">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; border-style: solid; border-color: #ffffff;">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-circle" src="./assets/img/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Mark Meyer</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Cabin 23412</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">EDIT</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            <td>Reservation ID</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Guests Associated</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reservation Date</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Special Request</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: It is almost, with the code above is the table (tbody) content mixed in its style. I had predefined width in % to each column.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: when you run the code snippet, the "CABIN" number i.e. 49222 is not directly under the "CABIN" header. The row content is floating to the left side, where the row items are suppose to stay under their header.

Comment: then you either let the header scroll with or apply the styles to each td element in the tboody too. Else this would turn into a  "write my code question"