# vertical scrollable table in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have trying to make scrollable **tbody** in flexbox.

I got two flexbox and each flexbox has table in it.

When items in table are overflow I want to use vertical scrollbar in tbody.

But tables are in flexbox that has no fixed height.

What should I do to show vertical scrollbar in tbody?

```css
.root {
  background-color:green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:4;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.container1 tbody {
  overflow: auto;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:3;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container1">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>age</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>age</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need more info. thanks.

Comment: You should add `display:block` in `tbody` and set fixed height as you want.

Comment: @Ivan I don't want fixed height

Comment: @JillAndMe  Please check below, i think it will solve the issue.

Comment: @AmarjitSingh thanks for your work, but I want to make scrollable only tbody

Comment: working on that !

Comment: to trigger a vertical scrollbar, you need either to set an height or a max-height to start with. Maybe this can help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771#23989771

Comment: yes, i am afraid you have to set a max-height.

Answer (score 0):

you should use overflow auto

**css**

```
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:4;
  background-color:yellow;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes please check !

```css
.root {
  background-color:green;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 30vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:4;
  background-color:yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


/* this flexbox is not appears!! */
.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:3;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container1">
    <table width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>age</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jhon</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Header is scrolled with the rest of the table.