# How to make table body vertically scrollable material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Property height doesn't apply to `tbody` element. Is it possible to make table body scrollable?

```
const styles = {
  tableBody: {
    height: 300,
    overflow: "auto"
  }
};
```

```
 <Paper className={classes.root}>
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody className={classes.tableBody}>
        {rows.map(row => (
          <TableRow key={row.name}>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              {row.name}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </Paper>
```

Sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigilant-night-zoidu

Comment: But table header should be always at the top and doesn't overflow

Comment: This solution brokes all table view

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll but not a proper fix as it messes style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the table components to divs with some css like this:

- With scrollable headers: https://codesandbox.io/s/ly8vvm5o19
- With sticky headers: https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-j54rg

Comment: Is it possible to make header fixed at the top and make body scrollable?

Comment: check the second link