# How to make sticky table's header without using col-md?

Tags: css

I need to created a table with sticky header, like [Here](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-table-with-a-fixed-header), the problem is that my th and td elements are created by repeater, so i can't calculate their correct percentage for bootstrap's col-md, and another problem is that i might have a table with more then 12 columns, so using col-md isn't going to wrork for me.

Html:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-fixed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="col-3">#</th> // don't want to use col-md
                            <th scope="col" class="col-3">First</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col-3">Last</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col-3">Handle</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">1</th>
                            <td class="col-3">Mark</td>
                            <td class="col-3">Otto</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">2</th>
                            <td class="col-3">Jacob</td>
                            <td class="col-3">Thornton</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">3</th>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-6">Larry the Bird</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@twitter</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">4</th>
                            <td class="col-3">Martin</td>
                            <td class="col-3">Williams</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@Marty</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">5</th>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-3">Sam</td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-3">Pascal</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@sam</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">6</th>
                            <td class="col-3">John</td>
                            <td class="col-3">Green</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@john</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">7</th>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-3">David</td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-3">Bowie</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@david</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">8</th>
                            <td class="col-3">Pedro</td>
                            <td class="col-3">Rodriguez</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@rod</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">5</th>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-3">Sam</td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-3">Pascal</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@sam</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">10</th>
                            <td class="col-3">Jacob</td>
                            <td class="col-3">Thornton</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" class="col-3">11</th>
                            <td colspan="2" class="col-6">Larry the Bird</td>
                            <td class="col-3">@twitter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Css

```
.table-fixed tbody {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
    display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed tbody th,
.table-fixed thead > tr > th {
    float: left;
    position: relative;

    &::after {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bootstrapious/dmp7tr4g/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=dmp7tr4g)

Comment: Please provide minimal code of your problem.

Comment: would `display:grid`/`display:contents` & `position:sticky` *( something similar https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WVXPNP )* be an option *(scroll will be for the entire table)* ? Might also be a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771

Comment: @RotemLurxHorovitz Thanks, but it's not what i need... i need to scroll only within the body of the table.... but without the use of col-md

Answer (score 0):

```css
 table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th, td {padding: 0.25rem;
}

th {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="red">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem.</td>
      <td>Ullam.</td>
      <td>Vel.</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Quis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quas!</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Quisquam?</td>
      <td>Rerum?</td>
      <td>Iusto?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptates!</td>
      <td>Fugiat?</td>
      <td>Alias.</td>
      <td>Doloribus.</td>
      <td>Veritatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maiores.</td>
      <td>Ab.</td>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Ullam!</td>
      <td>Eveniet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Id!</td>
      <td>Officiis.</td>
      <td>Modi!</td>
      <td>Obcaecati.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soluta.</td>
      <td>Ad!</td>
      <td>Impedit.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Ad.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Expedita.</td>
      <td>Quo.</td>
      <td>Exercitationem!</td>
      <td>Optio?</td>
      <td>Ipsum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Commodi!</td>
      <td>Rem.</td>
      <td>Aspernatur.</td>
      <td>Accusantium!</td>
      <td>Maiores.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Cumque?</td>
      <td>Eveniet!</td>
      <td>Mollitia?</td>
      <td>Vero.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Error!</td>
      <td>Inventore.</td>
      <td>Quasi!</td>
      <td>Ducimus.</td>
      <td>Repudiandae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolores!</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus.</td>
      <td>Corrupti!</td>
      <td>Eum.</td>
      <td>Sunt!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ea.</td>
      <td>Culpa?</td>
      <td>Quam?</td>
      <td>Nemo!</td>
      <td>Sit!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Veritatis!</td>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Expedita?</td>
      <td>Ipsam!</td>
      <td>Omnis!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vitae.</td>
      <td>Cumque.</td>
      <td>Repudiandae.</td>
      <td>Ut?</td>
      <td>Sed!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Adipisci.</td>
      <td>Sit.</td>
      <td>Maxime.</td>
      <td>Harum.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Qui!</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Minima?</td>
      <td>Dolorum.</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vero!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
      <td>Ea?</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>A.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Debitis.</td>
      <td>Veniam.</td>
      <td>Fuga.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Recusandae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aperiam!</td>
      <td>Dolorum.</td>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Sapiente!</td>
      <td>Suscipit?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequuntur.</td>
      <td>Doloremque.</td>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Iste!</td>
      <td>Sint!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Fugiat.</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Modi?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptatibus!</td>
      <td>Alias.</td>
      <td>Eaque.</td>
      <td>Cum.</td>
      <td>Ducimus!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Earum?</td>
      <td>Nobis?</td>
      <td>Eveniet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eum!</td>
      <td>Id?</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Minima.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sapiente?</td>
      <td>Neque.</td>
      <td>Obcaecati!</td>
      <td>Earum.</td>
      <td>Esse.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nam?</td>
      <td>Ipsam!</td>
      <td>Provident.</td>
      <td>Ullam.</td>
      <td>Quae?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amet!</td>
      <td>In.</td>
      <td>Officia!</td>
      <td>Natus?</td>
      <td>Tempore?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequatur.</td>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Officia.</td>
      <td>Itaque?</td>
      <td>Quasi.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Asperiores?</td>
      <td>Eos!</td>
      <td>Libero.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Exercitationem.</td>
      <td>Quidem!</td>
      <td>Beatae?</td>
      <td>Adipisci?</td>
      <td>Accusamus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Eius!</td>
      <td>Recusandae!</td>
      <td>Dolor.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magni.</td>
      <td>Temporibus!</td>
      <td>Odio!</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eum.</td>
      <td>Animi!</td>
      <td>Labore.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Fuga.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quia!</td>
      <td>Quis.</td>
      <td>Neque?</td>
      <td>Illo.</td>
      <td>Ad.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Officiis.</td>
      <td>Exercitationem!</td>
      <td>Adipisci?</td>
      <td>Officiis?</td>
      <td>In?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptates?</td>
      <td>Voluptatum.</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Totam?</td>
      <td>Quisquam!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soluta.</td>
      <td>Tempore!</td>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Beatae.</td>
      <td>Perspiciatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Porro.</td>
      <td>Officia?</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Culpa?</td>
      <td>Fugit.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Et?</td>
      <td>Nemo.</td>
      <td>Nisi?</td>
      <td>Totam!</td>
      <td>Voluptate.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Saepe?</td>
      <td>Vero.</td>
      <td>Amet?</td>
      <td>Illo!</td>
      <td>Laborum!</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Atque!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Optio.</td>
      <td>Iure.</td>
      <td>Porro.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Atque.</td>
      <td>Alias.</td>
      <td>Doloremque.</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Culpa.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeat?</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus.</td>
      <td>Voluptate!</td>
      <td>Possimus.</td>
      <td>Nam?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Quae.</td>
      <td>Expedita!</td>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Nam.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequuntur!</td>
      <td>Consectetur!</td>
      <td>Provident!</td>
      <td>Consequuntur!</td>
      <td>Distinctio.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aperiam!</td>
      <td>Voluptatem.</td>
      <td>Cupiditate!</td>
      <td>Quae.</td>
      <td>Praesentium.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Possimus?</td>
      <td>Qui.</td>
      <td>Consequuntur.</td>
      <td>Deleniti.</td>
      <td>Voluptas.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hic?</td>
      <td>Ab.</td>
      <td>Asperiores?</td>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Animi!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Libero.</td>
      <td>Iste.</td>
      <td>Dicta?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequatur!</td>
      <td>Nobis.</td>
      <td>Aperiam!</td>
      <td>Odio.</td>
      <td>Nemo!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolorem.</td>
      <td>Distinctio?</td>
      <td>Provident?</td>
      <td>Nisi!</td>
      <td>Impedit?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Accusantium?</td>
      <td>Ea.</td>
      <td>Doloribus.</td>
      <td>Nobis.</td>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
      <td>Rem?</td>
      <td>Enim!</td>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
      <td>Reiciendis!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Commodi.</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Earum?</td>
      <td>Fugit.</td>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligendi?</td>
      <td>Quis.</td>
      <td>Error?</td>
      <td>Atque.</td>
      <td>Perferendis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quidem.</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>Tempore.</td>
      <td>Voluptates.</td>
      <td>Facere!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Repudiandae!</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Soluta.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Aliquid?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quisquam?</td>
      <td>Eius.</td>
      <td>Obcaecati?</td>
      <td>Maxime.</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Minus.</td>
      <td>Magni?</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus?</td>
      <td>Asperiores.</td>
      <td>Iure.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ipsa!</td>
      <td>Temporibus.</td>
      <td>Non!</td>
      <td>Dolore.</td>
      <td>Veritatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ea!</td>
      <td>Officia?</td>
      <td>Doloribus?</td>
      <td>Deleniti?</td>
      <td>Dolorem!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sequi?</td>
      <td>Molestias!</td>
      <td>Nesciunt.</td>
      <td>Qui.</td>
      <td>Doloribus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id.</td>
      <td>Enim?</td>
      <td>Quam!</td>
      <td>Sunt!</td>
      <td>Consequuntur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Reprehenderit?</td>
      <td>Ut?</td>
      <td>Veritatis!</td>
      <td>Corporis!</td>
      <td>Ipsa.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blanditiis!</td>
      <td>Veniam!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Eos?</td>
      <td>Repellat!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enim?</td>
      <td>Atque!</td>
      <td>Aspernatur?</td>
      <td>Fugit.</td>
      <td>Voluptatibus!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Distinctio!</td>
      <td>Aut!</td>
      <td>Rerum!</td>
      <td>Dolorem?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inventore!</td>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Explicabo.</td>
      <td>Sit.</td>
      <td>A.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inventore.</td>
      <td>A.</td>
      <td>Nam.</td>
      <td>Beatae.</td>
      <td>Consequatur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligendi.</td>
      <td>Illum.</td>
      <td>Enim?</td>
      <td>Dignissimos!</td>
      <td>Ducimus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligendi!</td>
      <td>Fugiat?</td>
      <td>Deleniti!</td>
      <td>Rerum?</td>
      <td>Delectus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sit.</td>
      <td>Nam.</td>
      <td>Eveniet?</td>
      <td>Veritatis.</td>
      <td>Adipisci!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nostrum?</td>
      <td>Totam?</td>
      <td>Voluptates!</td>
      <td>Ab!</td>
      <td>Consequatur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Error!</td>
      <td>Dicta?</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
      <td>Corporis!</td>
      <td>Ea.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vel.</td>
      <td>Asperiores.</td>
      <td>Facere.</td>
      <td>Quae.</td>
      <td>Fugiat.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Libero?</td>
      <td>Molestias.</td>
      <td>Praesentium!</td>
      <td>Accusantium!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eveniet.</td>
      <td>Quam.</td>
      <td>Quibusdam.</td>
      <td>Eaque?</td>
      <td>Dolore!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Asperiores.</td>
      <td>Impedit.</td>
      <td>Ullam?</td>
      <td>Quod.</td>
      <td>Placeat.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>In?</td>
      <td>Aliquid.</td>
      <td>Voluptatum!</td>
      <td>Omnis?</td>
      <td>Magni.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Autem.</td>
      <td>Earum!</td>
      <td>Debitis!</td>
      <td>Eius.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blanditiis?</td>
      <td>Impedit.</td>
      <td>Libero?</td>
      <td>Reiciendis!</td>
      <td>Tempore.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quasi.</td>
      <td>Reiciendis.</td>
      <td>Aut?</td>
      <td>Architecto?</td>
      <td>Vero!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fuga!</td>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Tenetur!</td>
      <td>Vitae.</td>
      <td>Natus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolorem?</td>
      <td>Eaque!</td>
      <td>Vero?</td>
      <td>Quibusdam.</td>
      <td>Deleniti?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Minus.</td>
      <td>Accusantium?</td>
      <td>Ab.</td>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Atque?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Eligendi.</td>
      <td>Sit?</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Dolor.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quidem.</td>
      <td>In?</td>
      <td>Nesciunt?</td>
      <td>Adipisci.</td>
      <td>Neque.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eos.</td>
      <td>Incidunt!</td>
      <td>Quis?</td>
      <td>Quod?</td>
      <td>Vitae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ullam!</td>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Tempora!</td>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Consequuntur?</td>
    </tr>
    
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks - but the scrollbar should stay below the header....like in the example...