# Having problem with setting scroll in tbody of an html table - the alignments get ruined

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, scrollbar

I have a table like this:

```js
var mytable2 = "<tbody id='dynamic_table_2'><tr>";

for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 1 && i != 1) {
    mytable2 += "</tr'><tr>";
  }
  mytable2 += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
}
mytable2 += "</tr></tbody></table>";
$('#here2').append(mytable2);
```

```css
.container th h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #185875;
}

.container td {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container td,
.container th {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}


/* Background-color of the odd rows */

.container tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #323C50;
}


/* Background-color of the even rows */

.container tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #2C3446;
}

.container th {
  background-color: #1F2739;
}

.container td:first-child {
  color: #FB667A;
}

.container tr:hover {
  background-color: #464A52;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.container td:hover {
  background-color: #FFF842;
  color: #403E10;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 -2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
  transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container td:nth-child(4),
  .container th:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="container" id="here2" style="font-family: Arial">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h1>Column1</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column2</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column3</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column4</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column5</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Everything works fine and my table looks like [image: this image].

The problem starts when I want to use a vertical scroll bar for the `tbody` of this table.

From A LOT of searches mostly in SO, I finally found something that works but not perfectly. Others have recommended using `style='display:block;height:100px;overflow:auto;` for `tbody` and `style='display:table;table-layout:fixed;'` for `tr`s. When I do, the scroll bar is shown and usable but suddenly all of the cells are pulled to the right of `tbody` (I am using RTL settings) and it looks like this image:[image] which is not cool!
In fact the  cells of `tbody` are no more aligned with the cells in `thead`!!!!
I am really confused. I have tried a lot things but do not seem to figure out what to do to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scroll bar is not restyled in any browser where it is possible, its width is average `1.1rem`

You may then style `thead` minding this width, and set a `padding` or  set `thead` as a `block` with a `scrollbar` wich is  perfectly matching it own width via `overflow-x:scroll`.

option with `overflow-x:scroll` for `thead`

```js
var mytable2 = "<tbody id='dynamic_table_2'><tr>";

for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 1 && i != 1) {
    mytable2 += "</tr'><tr>";
  }
  mytable2 += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
}
mytable2 += "</tr></tbody></table>";
$('#here2').append(mytable2);
```

```css
.container th h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #185875;
}

.container td {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container td,
.container th {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}


/* Background-color of the odd rows */

.container tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #323C50;
}


/* Background-color of the even rows */

.container tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #2C3446;
}

.container th {
  background-color: #1F2739;
}

.container td:first-child {
  color: #FB667A;
}

.container tr:hover {
  background-color: #464A52;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.container td:hover {
  background-color: #FFF842;
  color: #403E10;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 -2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
  transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container td:nth-child(4),
  .container th:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
  }
}

tbody {
  display:block;height:100px;overflow:auto;
}
tr{display:table;table-layout:fixed;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="container" id="here2" style="font-family: Arial;">
  <thead style=" overflow-y:scroll;display:block;">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h1>Column1</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column2</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column3</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column4</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column5</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

or the average `padding` method on `thead` : *( which is actually a duplicate of [How to set tbody height with overflow scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771#23989771) )*

```js
var mytable2 = "<tbody id='dynamic_table_2'><tr>";

for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 1 && i != 1) {
    mytable2 += "</tr'><tr>";
  }
  mytable2 += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
}
mytable2 += "</tr></tbody></table>";
$('#here2').append(mytable2);
```

```css
.container th h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #185875;
}

.container td {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container td,
.container th {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}


/* Background-color of the odd rows */

.container tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #323C50;
}


/* Background-color of the even rows */

.container tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #2C3446;
}

.container th {
  background-color: #1F2739;
}

.container td:first-child {
  color: #FB667A;
}

.container tr:hover {
  background-color: #464A52;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.container td:hover {
  background-color: #FFF842;
  color: #403E10;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 -2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
  transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container td:nth-child(4),
  .container th:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
  }
}

tbody {
  display:block;height:100px;overflow:auto;
}
tr{display:table;table-layout:fixed;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="container" id="here2" style="font-family: Arial;">
  <thead style="padding-right:1.1rem;display:table;">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h1>Column1</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column2</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column3</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column4</h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>Column5</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

there is also the `display:grid` + `display:contents` option or the wrapper and `position:sticky`. If all of these CSS option seems not good enough, the last option is to relay on javascript .

Comment: Wow. I have been stuck with this for whole 3 days. It works. Thanks a lot. It seems the trick was using width:100%;