# Table with scrollable tbody and fixed header but with responsive width with text length

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table with `tbody` scrollable with `thead` fixed but the main condition is width should be based on `text length`.
I used following code but it have fixed width:

css:

```css
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
tbody {
  display:block;
  max-height:60vh;
  overflow:auto;
}

thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
```

kindly provide a  better solution for this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

Comment: i have to use that in angular 7.0 i tried that code still not working

Comment: I need tbody of the table to be in fixed hight and inside that  should be scrollable

Comment: Than this is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23989771/9863484