# thead and tbody column border misaligned on scroll in table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table, while scroll comes in `tbody` there is a misalignment in `thead` and `tbody` column borders.
Here is the example what I am trying to do:
[codepen table](https://codepen.io/animaxf/pen/JjXbrjB)

With scrollbar, it is working fine.

while scrollbar is not in `tbody` there is some misalignment of borders.
Is there any way to maintain the width of thead tr while scroll bar is present?

Comment: You shouldn't be using flexbox inside of a table: it defeats the purpose of table layout entirely. Anyway, the issue with your layout is that you are giving your `<thead>` element a width that is <100%.

Comment: just remove the width calc from the thead

Comment: @AhmedSunny if I remove the width the same problem appears while the scrollbar comes.

Comment: you may want to see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771#23989771

Comment: If hte link did not provide you any hints then, you may want to do `overflow-y: scroll;` instead `auto` for `tbody` ... also flex not needed here ;)  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBZqPKG

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try and use code snippets to display your code.

But your problem lies in your CSS on line 35:

```css
thead tr {
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
}
```

You say there is a misalignment in your thead and tbody, that's caused because you are taking 17px off 100% on `thead` and not on `tbody`

Comment: with scroll bar it is coming fine