# Table with scrollable tbody

Tags: html, css

I want a `<table>` where

- There is a max height.
- The header is fixed (is not affected by scroll).
- Column widths are calculated automatically (not fixed)
- No assumption is made on the height of `<thead>`.
- The solution uses pure css.

Is that possible?

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771) help?

Comment: Are you want like [this](https://codepen.io/pdg/pen/MayBJK)?

Comment: it could be possible : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abboqbR ... genuine table scrolling with fixed header  ...