# DataTable, with 100% width, max height and sticky header issue

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am trying to create a table that:

- Has 100% width
- Is limited to 500px in height
- Has a sticky thead

I appear to be in a loop with display: table vs display: block (and their inline- counterparts) both seem to make the opposite things work and break. display: block achieves the sticky header and fixed height, but it ignores the 100% width (for the tbody only in most cases) so I'll have a sticky 100% width thead, but a tbody that seems to fit itself into the bloated width of the first child of the thead. Applying display: table makes everything in the table 100% width, but, ignores the sticky thead and the maximum 500px height. I have tried putting it into an additional table-container applying the fixed height, this works to an extent, but ignores the sticky thead element and seems to make the tbody and thead columns different sizes, meaning they don't line up and appear under their respective thead.

#### display: table applied, 100% width, no fixed height or sticky header

[image: display: table applied, 100% width, no fixed height or sticky header]

#### display: block applied, fixed height and sticky header, no 100% width

[image: display: block applied, fixed height and sticky header, no 100% width]

Code:

```
        table {
    overflow: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

    table thead {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f21c0a;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 11;
    }


    table tr {
        background-color: white;
    }

        table tr:nth-child(odd):hover, table tr:nth-child(even):hover {
            background: #F8FFF5;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #f21c0a10 !important;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #fff;
        }



    table td:first-child {
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        /* box-shadow: -4px 14px 16px #3e3e3e50; */
        border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
        border-left: 0;
        background: inherit;
    }

    table th:first-child {
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        box-shadow: -4px 3px 16px #3e3e3e50;
    }

    table tbody {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: inherit;
    }

    table td {
        border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    }

table td, table th {
    /* padding: 10px; */
    width: 1px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
}

    table td:first-child, table th:first-child {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 1px;
        max-width: 1000px;
        text-align: left;
        border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
        z-index: 10;
        '}

        table th:first-child {
        z-index: 11;
    }
```

This is how datatables renders itself (I don't know where the inline 100% width comes from):

```
<table  id="tblFileTypes" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                type description
            </th>
            <th>
                filename contains
            </th>
            <th>
                production type
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/1">1</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bill
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bill%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Letter Upto 20pp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/2">2</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    Welcome Pack
                </td>
                <td>
                    WelcomePack%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Welcome Pack
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/3">3</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    Tariff Change
                </td>
                <td>
                    TariffChangeConfirmationLetter%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Letter Upto 20pp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/4">4</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    F001 : Bill Reminder 
                </td>
                <td>
                    %F001%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Letter Upto 20pp
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code rendering the table:

```
 function bindDatatable() {

        datatable = $('#tblFiles')
            .DataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetTableData","Faults")",
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bSearchable": false,
                "searching": false,
                "autowidth": false,
                "bAutowidth": false,
                "ordering": true,
                "order": [[1, 'asc']],
                "pageLength": 100,
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 999999], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "No Files found",
                    "processing":
                        '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" style="color:#2a2b2b;"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "id",
                        "searchable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "eon_file_name",
                        "searchable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "type_description",
                        "searchable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "datetime_added",
                        "searchable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "faults",
                        "searchable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        "targets": -1,
                        "defaultContent": "<button id='btnPDf' class='btn btn-primary'>View PDF</button>"
                    },

                ],
                createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    var $btn = $(row).find('#btnPDf');
                    var $td = $(row).find("td:eq(0)");
                    var id = $td.html();

                    $btn.click(function () {
                        ViewPdf(id);
                    });
                }

            });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please [Share your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Shouldn't be doing this but https://jsfiddle.net/sx1d4vue/

Comment: @GonzaloFaus that worked, but the issue of theads being bigger than tbody remains; 

https://ibb.co/68kTqbQ

Comment: @MaxiGui I have updated my post with the table CSS code.

Comment: Please provide html too with example that Gonzalo send sent. I would suggest you to set tbody as block and tr as table.

Comment: @MaxiGui added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the css that make the table at the end into custom CSS.

Inspire from: [How to set tbody height with overflow scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771)

```css
        table {
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    border-left: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

    table thead {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f21c0a;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 11;
    }


    table tr {
        background-color: white;
    }

        table tr:nth-child(odd):hover, table tr:nth-child(even):hover {
            background: #F8FFF5;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #f21c0a10 !important;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #fff;
        }



    table td:first-child {
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        /* box-shadow: -4px 14px 16px #3e3e3e50; */
        border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
        border-left: 0;
        background: inherit;
    }

    table th:first-child {
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        box-shadow: -4px 3px 16px #3e3e3e50;
    }

    table tbody {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: inherit;
    }

    table td {
        border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    }

table td, table th {
    /* padding: 10px; */
    width: 1px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
}

table td:first-child, table th:first-child {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 1px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  z-index: 10;
}

table th:first-child {
  z-index: 11;
}

/*** Custom css ****/

tbody{
  display: block;
}
tbody{
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height:150px;
}
thead, tbody tr{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
table th:first-child, table td:first-child{
  width: 15px;
}
table th, table td{
  width:auto;
}
table thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em );/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
```

```html
<table  id="tblFileTypes" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="/*width:100%*/">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                type description
            </th>
            <th>
                filename contains
            </th>
            <th>
                production type
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/1">1</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bill
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bill%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Letter Upto 20pp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/2">2</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    Welcome Pack
                </td>
                <td>
                    WelcomePack%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Welcome Pack
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/3">3</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    Tariff Change
                </td>
                <td>
                    TariffChangeConfirmationLetter%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Letter Upto 20pp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/FileType/Edit/4">4</a>                
                </td>
                <td>
                    F001 : Bill Reminder 
                </td>
                <td>
                    %F001%
                </td>
                <td>
                    Letter Upto 20pp
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks - only thing I had to change was the width: 1px parts to width: auto - they was causing the first column to crush themselves.

Comment: @Charlie Glad that it could help you! I also advice you to add `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to your `tbody td` to be sure that long word stays in cell, such as `TariffChangeConfirmationLetter%` in your 3rd line