# Fixing table header and making the table body scroll in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table, html-tbody

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-torvalds-gkh9n?file=/src/App.js) is a code sandbox URL, which contains React code for a table component,

I want to make the header in this component fixed at the top and the table body to be scrollable. For that, I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771). But if I make `tbody` as `display: block` and `thead` as `display: table` and do the changes as suggested in the above answer, then my table header columns won't align with my `tbody` columns, as attached in the screenshot here.

[image: Table header columns aren't aligned with Table body columns]

I want to make the header fixed at the top while the content of body should be scrollable and alignment shouldn't be disturbed. How can I achieve it? Can someone please help. Thanks a lot in advance.