# Bootstrap responsive table with scrollable tbody?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table and i append the contents of a db in its tbody,but i cant really get a responsive vertical scroll only in tbody only(with a fixed header),i tried to mess around with css and make the tbody display:block with overflow:auto and it kind of works but i lose responsiveness in the thead cell widths,they become shorter that the tbody cells.

is there a particular bootstrap class that can do this ?

```css
tbody{
max-height: 10vh;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css integrity=undefined crossorigin=anonymous>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-72WD92hLs7T5FAXn3vkNZflWG6pglUDDpm87TeQmfSg8KnrymL2G30R7as4FmTwhgu9H7eSzDCX3mjitSecKnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
<thead>
<tr><th>User</th><th>Action</th><th>Date</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `sticky-top` class and let the div container be the scrolling element via a custom class.

[`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) can help you to set a minimal height inside your `max-height` rule to, at least, see one row.Added also a white background to hide what scrolls behind .

possible example using mostly BS classes.

```css
.tbodyDiv{
max-height: clamp(5em,10vh,250px);
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css integrity=undefined crossorigin=anonymous>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-72WD92hLs7T5FAXn3vkNZflWG6pglUDDpm87TeQmfSg8KnrymL2G30R7as4FmTwhgu9H7eSzDCX3mjitSecKnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
hello i'm a sticky header
<div class="tbodyDiv">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
<thead class="sticky-top bg-white">
<tr><th>User</th><th>Action</th><th>Date</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>TESSSSSSSSSSST</td><td>TESSSST</td><td>T</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, however, the scroll bar is stretched not across ````<tbody>```` but across the whole ````<table>````. Is there a way to make the scroll bar just for ````<tbody>```` ?

Comment: @MikhailRatner , to only let tbody scroll requires to reset the table display of the whole table . display:grid could be an option, but will require lots of tunning to match your table. Once the table layout is reset , you loose it. no cols nor colspan nor rowspan is avalaible. here is a simple example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771#23989771

Answer (score 0):

I typed this code and got my answer.
It is really strange and illogical.
I checked it in chrome and firefox, Everything was correct.

I use bootstrap 5.

```css
table {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
thead>th, tbody tr, tbody>tr>th>{
    display: table;
    width: fit-content;
    table-layout: fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
table {
    width: 185px;
}
```