# Set child's height fixed to parent height

Tags: css, sass

There is a `div` which fills up the height of page. Then there is a table which needs to fill up the `div`s height. I need the `tbody` to get a scrollbar when it exceeds the height of table.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="data-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 11</td>
      <td>Data 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 21</td>
      <td>Data 22</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 190px);
  overflow: hidden;
  /* should not get scrollbar */
}

.data-table {
  /* needs to fill up wrapper height */

  tbody {
    /* needs to fill up table height and get scrollbar */
  }
}
```

I've tried the code below but did not succeed:

```
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 190px);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.data-table {
  height: 100%; /* and also inherit */
  
  tbody {
    height: 100%; /* and also inherit */
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `table` is not a good solution for this particular case. You can only achieve this if you change the `display` property of the `table` to `block`. If you do so, you break the layout and hence, it is best to use `div` since it is a `block` level element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771

Comment: You could wrap the `table` in an extra `div` and add the `max-height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll` to that div.