# Custom horizontal scrollbar is still pushing content up even when overflow-x is set to overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a div that includes content that extends beyond the right side of the screen. Thus, I use a custom horizontal scrollbar situated at the bottom of the screen to navigate to the end of the div. The problem is that my custom horizontal scrollbar is pushing my content upwards. To fix this, I thought one simply had to change the overflow-x from auto or scroll to overlay so the scrollbar doesn't take up any physical space / shift the content... but unfortunately this is not working. To see the subtle shift, change the height of the custom scrollbar from 5% to 0% and you'll see that the yellow div is being shifted. Any idea why this is happening? I do not want the scrollbar to shift any of my content, which is what I thought overlay accomplished.

*To clarify*, I am not looking to remove the scrollbar. I need the scrollbar. The problem is that the scrollbar is ever so slightly shifting my content upwards. It is very subtle, the way you can see it happen is to remove the scrollbar and you'll see that the content is shifted. I need the content exactly where it would be if there was no scrollbar, but I need the scrollbar. If you're still struggling to see the shift, change the height of the scrollbar to something extreme like 50%. Impossible to miss then.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kcmpquL/

```
  <div id="horizontalstorecontainer">
    <div class="store-scrolling-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 5%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: white;
}

#horizontalstorecontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

.store-scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: overlay;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 60%;
    width: 300%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: If your scrollbar is overlaying the content, won't some content at the bottom side be "overlayed", thus hard or even impossible to see?

Comment: Yes, but I'll never be placing content that far down.

Answer (score 2):

i only get this when i use 'show' on the overflow, when i use 'overlay' the scrollbutton and the yellow content touch, no space between, even at 50%.

overlay is not considered a valid value:

```
overlay: non-standard value only supported by the WebKit-browsers that does the same as auto.
```

It's possibly a browser issue:

[Overflow: overlay doesn't work in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543664/overflow-overlay-doesnt-work-in-firefox/8544173)

problem is , it's not a standard. So if it works, great, but if it doesn't...
you can always check if you need a reliable source:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#propdef-overflow-x

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-4/

Comment: Strange. I'm not using firefox. I'm also testing in Safari and Chrome and 'overlay' is absolutely not working as it should on my end...  On the link you provided the answers states 'The difference between overlay and auto would only be that the scrollbars would appear over the top of the page content, and not cause it to take layout space.' Unfortunately this is not happening with my code even in webkit browsers... scrollbar is taking up page estate and affecting all my content every time :(

Comment: Dont take my word for it; i added a few links for an answer from a reputable source

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to make ::webkit-scrollbar take no space as you're asking. 
But you could easily hack this problem by changing the value of the `transform` property you're using to center the content.

For example, if you want to use a bar with a 5% height then write:

```
transform: translateY(-45%);
```

instead of

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: You're welcome. From what I understood, you can not make your scrollbar kind of float over your content using `::-webkit-scrollbar` only.
It will take some space and push it, unless it has `position: fixed;` but then it's not scrollable anymore.
So the only solution is to compensate the space taken by the scrollbar by moving your content back into position.

Comment: Understood. Such a bummer! You'd think a scrollbar that takes up no space would be simple and definitely not need a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

When i tested it out, using your code, i didn't notice any shift in the content. It content remained where it was... So its either you didn't upload the right code or maybe there was no problem of such in the first place...

But should in case you're still having the problem, try adding this to your CSS:

**Edited**

So isn't actually pushing your contents upwards, and as a matter of fact, `overflow-x: overlay` is giving its expected result. The `scrollbar-track` is only going over the content and not pushing it. Change the background color of the `scrollbar-track` to something other than transparent and see it go over your element.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: red;
}
```

Then you could probably give the content a visible border(just for debugging, lets you see where its edges are)

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 300%;
    top: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 10; // this doesn't fix it either
    border: 2px solid red; // just for debugging
}
```

Having done this, when you change the height of your scrollbar, you'll notice that, the content's border-bottom would not be visible again, this is because the 
scrollbar went over it..

A possible fix would be to give the content a height value in any either px or em....(anything other than %)

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; // height not in %
}
```

Comment: Look at the JSFiddle in the question and you'll see the shift if you remove the scrollbar and then add it again. It is small, but it is there. I've tried adding the border-box style, but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: i honestly didn't see any change in its position... i went as far as putting a custom marker just below the content and changed the scrollbar's height to 0%....and still didn't see any change. The content remained where the marker was

Comment: Try changing the height of the scrollbar to something extreme then like 50%. The shift will be impossible to miss.

Comment: Thanks for looking further into this, but when debugging, it still appears that this is not what is happening. Here (https://ibb.co/zJDFtZb) is a screenshot of what I'm showing. The bottom border is not being covered up (if it were, there would be none of the blue background shown beneath the yellow content). It still appears that not only is the scrollbar shifting the content upwards, it's also reducing the height of the content itself.

Comment: Hi JOhn, ik only get this when i use 'show' on the overflow, when i use 'overlay' the scrollbutton and the yellow content touch, no space between, even at 50%. What browser are you using?  see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543664/overflow-overlay-doesnt-work-in-firefox/8544173

Comment: Hello, strange as I'm only using webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem it was being pushed up because of the height.
This is my first post please support me Guys.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
width: auto;
height: 0px;}
```