# Table's scrollbar pushing text to left?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I can't figure out why my browser (latest Chrome) keeps adding space between my table cells and the scrollbar (I highlighted in red):

[image]

When I put my table HTML in JSFiddle, it does *not* have this extra space (https://jsfiddle.net/m0c3twda/1/).

```css
.table-container{
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right:  auto;
    width: 80vw;  /* set the width of the table to 80% of view width */
}

#image-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: visible;
    height: 100px;
    display:  block;
    width:  100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#image-list tr{
    display: table-row;
    padding:  0px;
}

#image-list td{
    padding-left:  3px;
    padding-right:  3px;
}

#image-list tr td:first-child{
    text-align: left;
}

#image-list tr td:nth-child(2){
    text-align: center;
}

#image-list tr td:nth-child(3){
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='table-container'>
        <table id='image-list'>
            <tr class="row">
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/Chrysanthemum%20-%20Copy.jpg"> Chrysanthemum - Copy.jpg </a></td>
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/Chrysanthemum.jpg"> Chrysanthemum.jpg </a></td>
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/Desert%20-%20Copy.jpg"> Desert - Copy.jpg </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/Desert.jpg"> Desert.jpg </a></td>
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/Hydrangeas%20-%20Copy.jpg"> Hydrangeas - Copy.jpg </a></td>
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/Hydrangeas.jpg"> Hydrangeas.jpg </a></td>
            </tr>

            ...

            <tr class="row">
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/test%20%282%29.jpg"> test (2).jpg </a></td>
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/test%20%283%29.jpg"> test (3).jpg </a></td>
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/test%20%284%29.jpg"> test (4).jpg </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td><a class="image-link" href="/index/Tulips.jpg"> Tulips.jpg </a></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0c3twda/1/  -- **note:** there are more rows in the JSFiddle, I just posted a few here for simplicity.

I've also tried `html {overflow-y: scroll}` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297846/4650297) but same thing happens.

For some reason I suspect it's in the `.table-container{}` css, except if I remove that completely, it still adds space between the third column and the scrollbar...

There's no Javascript/jQuery, etc. It's all HTML + CSS (although it's generated via Flask).

What might I be overlooking, or not considering?

Comment: Is the class="row" referencing Bootstrap on the <tr> tags

Comment: If you stretch the JSFiddle it will eventually have that white space. Looks like that's just where the text ends and that's the width of `tbody`

Comment: @JakeG - No, I'm not using Bootstrap.  I set that class up originally for CSS, but never used it.  I removed `class="row"` from `tr` and also `class="image-link"` from the `a` tags to see what happens, and I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got a few things going on here that would need reconsidered; [See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpcmqbko/1/) with some visual aids added.

For starters, there's no reason to change the `display`, it's a table, let it be a table. By changing it to `block` the nested tr's lose track of what they're supposed to be in context and chrome will apply a `<tbody>` around your rows and the single `<td>` at the end will always cause layout issues since it's basically a broken tag if it's missing a `colspan` to act as a valid row with columns when measured/arranged/painting.

We also let the container handle the `overflow` and let `border-collapse` handle the reduction of spacing as an attribute of `display: table` instead of targeting `td` as a child of a `display: block` as mentioned before.

Either way, hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your answer and explanations!  I need to read up more on `border-collapse` and tables generally.  In `#image-list`, does removing the `display` do the same thing as if I did `display: table`?

Comment: Don't over think it. Let the defaults do their job, like `display: table` on a `<table>` element is redundant because it's already a table, and the browser already applies that css property for you anyway. Familiarity with the [css box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) will also make life easier :)

Comment: Oh, I was just asking to make sure it was redundant to do that :P ...I've been learning HTML/CSS and lots of the suggestions are very ...odd. I didn't add `block` display just cause...I swear I must have seen that in some rabbit-hole solution to another question I had, so I'm working my way to success, one kludge at a time!! :D  (And thanks for the link, very much appreciated!)

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.